# how to close a workbook using vba from another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I had opened a second workbook when user clicks new workbook command button in userform, the problem is when user clicks logout button on this userform the newly created workbook should be closed.how to achive this??

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open("Your Path here including filename")

wb.Close
```